# Big difference between val-acc and train accuracy in Keras Neural Network

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I found that the validation data converges significantly slower than train data during training, so I replaced validation data with train data, and the loss of validation `val_loss` is still significantly slower than the training loss, why is this? Can anyone answer my question?
[image: img]

The curve is shown in the graph.

[image: img]
code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import applications
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import LearningRateScheduler
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
base_model = applications.MobileNetV2(input_shape=(224,224,3),weights='imagenet',include_top=False)

inputs=tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(224,224,3))
x=base_model(inputs)#此处x为MobileNetV2模型去处顶层时输出的特征相应图。
x=tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
outputs=tf.keras.layers.Dense(133,activation='softmax')(x)
model=tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=inputs,outputs=outputs)
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.001,momentum=0.9)
import os
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False),
              metrics=['sparse_categorical_accuracy'],)

checkpoint_save_path = "./checkpoint/mobilenetv2.ckpt"
if os.path.exists(checkpoint_save_path + '.index'):
    print('-------------load the model-----------------')
    model.load_weights(checkpoint_save_path)
    
def scheduler(epoch):
    # 每隔10个epoch，学习率减小为原来的1/10
    if epoch % 10 == 0 and epoch != 0:
        lr = K.get_value(model.optimizer.lr)
        K.set_value(model.optimizer.lr, lr * 0.95)
        print("lr changed to {}".format(lr * 0.95))
    return K.get_value(model.optimizer.lr)
 
reduce_lr = LearningRateScheduler(scheduler)

cp_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=checkpoint_save_path,
                                                 save_weights_only=True,
                                                 save_best_only=True)

history = model.fit(train_x,train_y, batch_size=4, epochs=20, validation_data=(train_x,train_y), validation_freq=1,
                    callbacks=[cp_callback,reduce_lr])
# history = model.fit(train_data, batch_size=4, epochs=20, validation_data=val_data, validation_freq=1,
#                     callbacks=[cp_callback,reduce_lr])
```

```
Epoch 1/20
  2/215 [..............................] - ETA: 5s - loss: 5.1054 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.0000e+00WARNING:tensorflow:Callbacks method `on_train_batch_end` is slow compared to the batch time (batch time: 0.0130s vs `on_train_batch_end` time: 0.0379s). Check your callbacks.
215/215 [==============================] - 12s 58ms/step - loss: 4.4875 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.0291 - val_loss: 4.8017 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.0105
Epoch 2/20
215/215 [==============================] - 12s 54ms/step - loss: 3.7271 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.0698 - val_loss: 5.4774 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.0081
Epoch 3/20
215/215 [==============================] - 11s 53ms/step - loss: 2.9440 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.1802 - val_loss: 4.9705 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.0291
Epoch 4/20
215/215 [==============================] - 12s 55ms/step - loss: 2.3213 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.3163 - val_loss: 4.1974 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.0558
Epoch 5/20
215/215 [==============================] - 12s 54ms/step - loss: 1.6388 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.5163 - val_loss: 4.2031 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.0395
Epoch 6/20
215/215 [==============================] - 12s 54ms/step - loss: 1.0936 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.7035 - val_loss: 3.8308 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.0895
Epoch 7/20
215/215 [==============================] - 12s 54ms/step - loss: 0.6046 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.8651 - val_loss: 3.6757 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.1407
Epoch 8/20
215/215 [==============================] - 12s 56ms/step - loss: 0.4002 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9186 - val_loss: 3.3228 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.2384
Epoch 9/20
215/215 [==============================] - 12s 56ms/step - loss: 0.2533 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9593 - val_loss: 3.1674 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.2547
Epoch 10/20
215/215 [==============================] - 12s 55ms/step - loss: 0.1698 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9767 - val_loss: 2.4485 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.3686
lr changed to 0.0009500000451225787
Epoch 11/20
215/215 [==============================] - 12s 55ms/step - loss: 0.1416 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9826 - val_loss: 1.2818 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.6721
Epoch 12/20
215/215 [==============================] - 12s 55ms/step - loss: 0.1119 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9849 - val_loss: 1.1645 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.7163
Epoch 13/20
215/215 [==============================] - 12s 55ms/step - loss: 0.0790 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9965 - val_loss: 0.2560 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9477
Epoch 14/20
215/215 [==============================] - 12s 57ms/step - loss: 0.0718 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9965 - val_loss: 0.1067 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9814
Epoch 15/20
215/215 [==============================] - 12s 55ms/step - loss: 0.0641 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9953 - val_loss: 0.1339 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9651
Epoch 16/20
215/215 [==============================] - 12s 54ms/step - loss: 0.0440 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9977 - val_loss: 0.0210 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 17/20
215/215 [==============================] - 12s 56ms/step - loss: 0.0322 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9988 - val_loss: 0.0040 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 18/20
215/215 [==============================] - 12s 56ms/step - loss: 0.0351 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9977 - val_loss: 0.0020 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 19/20
215/215 [==============================] - 12s 54ms/step - loss: 0.0299 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9988 - val_loss: 0.0091 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9988
Epoch 20/20
215/215 [==============================] - 12s 54ms/step - loss: 0.0402 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9977 - val_loss: 0.0292 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9965
```

Comment: This is impossible to answer without more information, and even in that case this might not be on-topic here. Other than your model is just overfitting.

Comment: I have updated my code.

Answer (score 0):

Your image is showing the loss values during the initial epochs. I see not much wrong here, the training loss should be lower than the validation loss initially. Over time, the validation loss should become lower and it should be around the training loss. So you should keep training until the validation loss becomes lower.

Some pointers to keep track (taken from [here](https://forums.fast.ai/t/determining-when-you-are-overfitting-underfitting-or-just-right/7732/3)):

- Typically validation loss should be similar to but slightly higher
  than training loss.
- As long as validation loss is lower than or even
  equal to training loss one should keep doing more training.
- If training loss is reducing without an increase in validation loss then
  again keep doing more training If validation loss starts increasing
  then it is time to stop

Comment: Can you explain why trainacc is significantly higher than valacc at epoch 5, when train and val use the same data?

Comment: @ChakloongChong its cause the model is overfitting the data at that epoch. What are the final results though? Could you include the final results? Or perhaps add checkpoints to save the best model on an epoch basis.

Comment: Is everyone just going to ignore the fact that OP gets this behavior even if they use _the same data_ for training and validation? Overfitting simply does not apply in this case.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy@yudhiesh  I have updated some of the results. Where train and val use the same data. I hope you can provide answers.

Comment: @xdurch0 sorry, i don't know what is OP, could you explain this?

Comment: OP means original poster, i.e. you. Unfortunately I can't really add anything useful on the question itself, since we are lacking crucial information, such as the definition of the model as well as the data. It might be that there are components in the model that behave differently for training and validation, but this is of course just speculation without seeing the relevant code.

Comment: @xdurch0 Thankyou, i just use the classic model mobilenetv2 for classification task.

Comment: @xdurch0 i have updated my code, so you can see my definition of the model.